# how to scale bitmaps

Tags: android, bitmap

How to scale bitmaps at runtime to a very small size and then storing them in internal storage? how to call the scaled bitmaps into the program from the storage at runtime and if its not there, call it from drawable folder, scale it, write it to storage and then bind it to the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to scale the bitmap you could use [Bitmap.createScaledBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29)

To scale an arbitrary bitmap to 32x32 you could do it as follows:

```
Bitmap smallBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap( fullSizeBitmap, 32,  32,  true );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BitmapFactory.Options` class to crop image to any size.

You can use following:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
options.inSampleSize = 8; // 1/8th of actual image.
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, options);
int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
String imageType = options.outMimeType;
```

Here, when you use a Bitmap, always call its `bmp.recycle()` method, since GC can't clear the memory held by Bitmap, if your bitmap is not getting garbage collected, then also you get the OME.

Comment: :I have seen your answer & installed MAT,checked where the memory leak is happening.the thing is I have an app with 7 activities & in these 7 has grid of images,books etc.and Here I am adding variable background to grid view.the thing is transition among the activities is done by left and right swiping..when i swipe continuously among the activities,and at 50th time swiping I am getting this error..If u understand my bug,please debug it.And the thing is I have tried using all kinds of methods to get rid of this like by using options,weak reference, bitmap.recycle(),system.gc().etc..

Comment: After checking from MAT, have you found any memory leak?